# cython - segmentation fault when assigning c++ class instance pointers

Tags: c++, python, segmentation-fault, cython

I am new to cython and am trying to wrap some existing c++ code with cython so that they can be used in python. A much simplified version of my problem is as follows.

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class A
{
public:
    int value;
    A(int x);
    void printA();
};
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
A::A(int x)
{
    std::cout<<"entering A constructor"<<std::endl;
    value = x;
    std::cout<<"exiting A constructor"<<std::endl;

}
void A::printA()
{
    std::cout<<"print value in A :"<<value<<std::endl;
}
```

cmd.h

```
#include "A.h"
class CMD
{
public:
    A *a;
    void init(int x);
    void test();

};
```

cmd.cpp

```
#include "cmd.h"
#include <iostream>
void CMD::init(int x)
{
    std::cout<<"start initializing A"<<std::endl;
    a = new A(x); // this line is causing the segmentation fault
    std::cout<<"end initializing A"<<std::endl;
}

void CMD::test()
{
    std::cout<<"start printing A"<<std::endl;
    a->printA();
    std::cout<<"end printing A"<<std::endl;

}
```

PyCMD.pyx

```
cdef extern from "cmd.h":
    # cdef cppclass A:
    #     A(int x)
    cdef cppclass CMD:
        # A *a
        CMD()
        void init(int x)
        void test()

cdef class PyCMD:
    cdef CMD *thisptr
    def __cint__(self):
        self.thisptr = new CMD()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def init(self, x):
        self.thisptr.init(x)
    def test(self):
        self.thisptr.test()
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("cmdtest", ["PyCMD.pyx","cmd.cpp","A.cpp"],language='c++')]
)
```

helloword.py

```
from cmdtest import *
d = PyCMD()
d.init(10)
d.test()
```

The program is very simple. Class A simply has a constructor and a method to print the value in A. Class cmd creates an instance of A in its init() method and call A's printA() method inside test(). The cython code basically creates a cdef class PyCMD that mimics all methods available in cmd class. When I run the helloworld.py, the output is as follows.

```
start initializing A
entering A constructor
exiting A constructor
[1]    11689 segmentation fault  {my_python_path}
```

Clearly, the segmentation fault happens when assigning the pointer of A instance. I then wrote a main.cpp to make sure that at least the c++ code is solid.

main.cpp

```
#include "cmd.h"
int main()
{
    CMD *cmd = new CMD();
    cmd->init(10);
    cmd->test();
}
```

The output looks fine.

```
start initializing A
entering A constructor
exiting A constructor
end initializing A
start printing A
print value in A :10
end printing A
```

The problem should be with cython but i have no idea where that is.

I'm very grateful for any help.

Comment: That can't be your actual code, because there's an obvious `SyntaxError` in setup.py. There's an obvious fix for it, but it would be nice to know we're debugging the same code you're running instead of something kind of similar that may or may not have the same problem.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed the issue and tested all the code. It should be error free now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an initializer for `PyCMD`, so `thisptr` is uninitialized.

You can see this is you just print out `self.thisptr` anywhere in the Cython code, or `this` in the C++ code.

You do have a function that *looks* like an initializer… but because it's called `__cint__` instead of `__cinit__`, it's not.

So, the equivalent C++ code is something like this:

```
#include "cmd.h"
int main()
{
    CMD *cmd;
    cmd->init(10);
    cmd->test();
}
```

… which gives the exact same segfault.

Comment: lifesaver! i spent hours trying to find the problem and you spotted it right away! thanks so much!

Comment: @pippo: For reference, the way I spotted it was by adding printing into every function—C++, Cython, and Python—and noticing that `__cinit__` never got called, which made me wonder why, at which point I realized that the string in the message didn't match the method name. But really, this is probably one of those cases where any fresh eyes will work, and mine were just the first fresh eyes on your code.

Comment: good point! thanks again for letting me know how you spotted it.